# Playing DVDs on chromebook using crouton

Tags: ubuntu, dvd, chrome-book

I am aware that Chromebooks cannot play DVDs normally but I wanted to know if connecting an external DVD drive via USB and trying to play in something like VLC media player would enable someone to watch a DVD on a chromebook?

A Google search proved inconclusive to me with one or two claims of success but most people saying it can't be done. I gather 'codecs' are something necessary to decode the raw data from the DVD which chromebooks don't have but could be downloaded to a linux OS? Another idea I came across suggested that you only need to change permissions and then it would work.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I took the plunge and bought a drive and am pleased to say I got it working.

In case anyone else is interested, I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdcss libdvdread4 libdvdnav4
```

from the command line. libdvdcss didn't install properly, but it seems this is a known problem which can be fixed by running:

```
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

After that, I simply opened the DVD from VLC player (which I'd previously installed) and voila!

I know this is the standard procedure for playing DVDs in Linux; however, I am noting that it also works running Linux on a Chromebook through Crouton because for some reason there are a lot of people on other forums saying it wouldn't work. (Many who hadn't tried it)

Hopefully this will help clear things up for people wondering if they can watch DVDs on Chromebooks in the future.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. You say this works using Linux via Crouton. Would it also work using the Linux virtual machine installed via the Chromebook's settings?

Comment: Update: I tried doing this in the Linux VM and couldn't get it to work, at least with my external DVD drive.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment as I've just signed in, just wanted to add I could not run VLC with root/sudo and it still would not play my disk (/dev/sr0: permission denied shown in the log), so I altered the dvd device to be readable by all and it worked. On my machine it was this command:

```
sudo chmod a+r /dev/sr0
```